# Grouping measures in Tabular model

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I have a Tabular model cube, and when analyzing the data in power pivot, the measures are grouped with the same name as the table name. I want to include all the measures in one group(folder) called Values. Is it possible to do that?
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

W Tabular Model we can group measures in a folder in Table.
I am using TabularEditor to work with the model. On measure level you can set "Display Folder"

[image]

Comment: Yes, this will display the measures in one folder under the table name. Is it possible to change the table name only for the measures?
For example, if the display folder name is Values
then this will display values under the table name Sales
I want to change the table name Sales to values, only for the measures.

Comment: If you connect to your model from excel, then in PivotTable you find measures under "FolderName"; Where do you want to display this folder?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply; right now, the measure group is under the original table name Sales, so first you get sales, and when you expand Sales, you get the measure group; what I want is to list the measure group at the same level, not under Sales.